How can I load a .glb model from the assets folder in NextJS?
I'm trying to load a .glb model in NextJS.
Everything works fine in dev, but building throws an error:
TypeError: Failed to parse URL from /models/xbox-regular.glb
cause:
 TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL
      at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
      at new URL (node:internal/url:560:13)
      at new Request (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:7041:25)
      at FileLoader.load (...)
      at GLTFLoader.load (...)

The file is at this path:
public\models\xbox-regular.glb
My code looks like this:
"use client"
import { OrbitControls, Stage } from '@react-three/drei'
import { Canvas, useLoader } from '@react-three/fiber';
import { Suspense, useMemo } from 'react';
import { Color, MeshToonMaterial } from 'three';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader';

const Gltf = ({ modelName, ...props }: { modelName: string, props?: unknown }) => {
    const modelPath = `/models/${modelName}`;

    const { scene, materials, nodes } = useLoader(GLTFLoader, modelPath);

    useMemo(() => {
        const greyLevel = 0.06372078508138657;
        const replacementHandMaterial = new MeshToonMaterial({ color: new Color(greyLevel, greyLevel, greyLevel)});
        materials['Material.002'] = replacementHandMaterial;
        (nodes['RHand'] as any).material = replacementHandMaterial;
        (nodes['RHand001'] as any).material = replacementHandMaterial;
    }, [nodes, materials]);

    return (
        <div style={{ width: "100vw", height: "100vh" }}>
            <Canvas>
                <ambientLight intensity={0.25} />
                <Suspense fallback={null}>
                <Stage
                    preset="rembrandt"
                    intensity={1}
                    shadows="contact"
                    adjustCamera
                    environment="city">
                    <primitive object={scene} />
                </Stage>
                <OrbitControls makeDefault autoRotate />
                </Suspense>
            </Canvas>
        </div>
    )
}

How can I get NextJS to ignore this error/this component on build? I thought the "use client" directive should be enough to mark the component as client-side.
EDIT:
My next Config file looks like this:
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    webpack (config, options) {
        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /.*\.(glb|gltf)$/,
            use: {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            }
        })
        return config;
    },
    typescript: {
        ignoreBuildErrors: true
    }
}

module.exports = nextConfig

As mentioned above, this works in dev, so I don't think it's a config error.

The solution was that I had to use:
"use client"
in the component that used the <Gltf /> as well.
Solution looks like:
"use client"
import { Gltf } from "@/render/gltf/Gltf";
import { createTitleFromParams } from "@/text/title";
import { GetStaticPaths, Metadata } from "next";
import { GameControllerGripParams } from "./params";

const GameControllerGrip = ({
  params
}: GameControllerGripParams) => {
  const controllerType = params['controller-type'];
  const gripName = params['grip-name'];
  return <>
    <h1>{createTitleFromParams({ params })}</h1>
    <Gltf
      modelName={`${controllerType}-${gripName}.glb`}
    />
  </>
};

I believe that you need to 'use client' at the level where your dynamic parameters (in this case modelName) are first defined.

I encountered the same problem, it turned out to be simple
You need to use for .glb hook (HOST - local url host system):
const { scene: buttonObject } = useGLTF(HOST + '/model.glb')

And for scene loading:
const SceneMain = dynamic(() =>
   import('@/components/scenes/SceneMain').then((mod) => mod.SceneMain),
   {
       ssr: false
   }
)

You can also use for optimization:
useGLTF.preload(HOST + "/model.glb")

